# Rails / Postgres Lookup Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance, postgresql

I have a status dashboard that shows the status of remote hardware devices that 'ping' the application every minute and log their status.

```
class Sensor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logs

  def most_recent_log
    logs.order("id DESC").first
  end
end

class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sensor
end
```

Given I'm only interested in showing the current status, the dashboard only shows the most recent log for all sensors. This application has been running for a long time now and there are tens of millions of `Log` records.

The problem I have is that the dashboard takes around 8 seconds to load. From what I can tell, this is largely because there is an N+1 Query fetching these logs.

```
Completed 200 OK in 4729.5ms (Views: 4246.3ms | ActiveRecord: 480.5ms)
```

I do have the following index in place:

```
add_index "logs", ["sensor_id", "id"], :name => "index_logs_on_sensor_id_and_id", :order => {"id"=>:desc}
```

My controller / lookup code is the following:

```
class SensorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sensors = Sensor.all
  end
end
```

---

1. How do I make the load time reasonable?
2. Is there a way to avoid the N+1 and reload this?

---

I had thought of putting a `latest_log_id` reference on to `Sensor` and then updating this every time a new log for that sensor is posted - but something in my head is telling me that other developers would say this is a bad thing. Is this the case?

How are problems like this usually solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 relatively easy ways to do this:

- Use ActiveRecord eager loading to pull in just the most recent logs
- Roll your own mini eager loading system (as a Hash) for just this purpose

Basic ActiveRecord approach:

```
subquery = Log.group(:sensor_id).select("MAX('id')")
@sensors = Sensor.eager_load(:logs).where(logs: {id: subquery}).all
```

Note that you should NOT use your `most_recent_log` method for each sensor (that will trigger an N+1), but rather `logs.first`.  Only the latest log for each sensor will actually be prefetched in the `logs` collection.

Rolling your own may be more efficient from a SQL perspective, but more complex to read and use:

```
@sensors = Sensor.all
logs = Log.where(id: Log.group(:sensor_id).select("MAX('id')"))
@sensor_logs = logs.each_with_object({}){|log, hash|
  hash[log.sensor_id] = log
}
```

`@sensor_logs` is a Hash, permitting a fast lookup for the latest log by `sensor.id`.

Regarding your comment about storing the latest log id - you are essentially asking if you should build a cache.  The answer would be 'it depends'.  There are many advantages and many disadvantages to caching, so it comes down to 'is the benefit worth the cost'.  From what you are describing, it doesn't appear that you are familiar with the difficulties they introduce (Google 'cache invalidation') or if they are applicable in your case.  I'd recommend against it until you can demonstrate that a) it is adding real value over a non-cache solution, and b) it can be safely applied for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - With the amount of data I have this does however just appear to shift the problem: https://gist.github.com/digitaldawn/82fff758ddc8425ec17c53f1b8c924d9 - Is there a better index I should be using or should I be looking at the caching option?

Comment: It appears that the query could use some improvement.  Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608771/postgresql-select-max-from-rows), I'd suggest trying `Log.select('DISTINCT ON (sensor_id) logs.*').order('sensor_id, id DESC')` instead of using `group` with MAX(id).  Also, can you estimate how many Sensor records you actually have (considering you're calling `.all`)?

Comment: I have 181 sensors right now - but this will potentially run up to 1000. I also have 27 Million Logs. The Distinct Query actually took longer (91 seconds to run). See: https://gist.github.com/digitaldawn/b47b1c0883e2f7f121eeb4e18e6e8531

Comment: Given the above, is caching going to be the best option here? `Logs` themselves within the application only have a single entry point and are never modified.

Comment: Hmm, it's using an index scan, and I'm not aware of anything faster that Postgres can offer :(. At this point, you either need a PostgreSQL expert or resort to a cache.  @ErwinBrandstetter anything you can recommend here?

Answer (score 1):

There's 3 options:

1. eager loading
2. joining
3. caching the current status

--

1. is explained by PinnyM
2. You can do a join from the Sensor just to the latest Log record for each row, so everything gets fetched in the one query. Not sure off hand how that'll perform with the number of rows you have, likely it'll still be slower than you want.
3. The thing you mentioned - caching the `latest_log_id` (or even caching just the `latest_status` if that's all you need for the dashboard) is actually OK. It's called [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and it's a useful thing if used carefully. You've likely come across "counter cache" plugins for rails which are in the same vein - duplicating data, in the interests of being able to optimise read performance.

Comment: Note that 2. above is actually what ActiveRecord will perform when using `eager_load` (albeit by LEFT JOIN).  A classic (INNER) JOIN should not be used here unless you are sure that at least one Log entry will always exist for a given Sensor.  See my answer above about the pitfalls of caching - use with care.